# Valor da div sendo enviada dinamicamente para página php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um simples jogo que ao final gera uma pontuação.
A pontuação aparece desta forma:

```
<div id='cScore'>0</div></div>
```

Eu gostaria de no momento que essa div é chamada que essa pontuação fosse enviada também para a página processa.php, usando um form por exemplo.

---

Mais detalhes: o que eu preciso mesmo é salvar esse valor no banco de dados juntamente com o nome do usuário da página, pensei em enviar para uma página "processa.php" pq lá eu conseguiria desenvolver isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa de um formulário para mandar este valor para o back-end, para isto você pode usar **`Ajax`** para conhecer sobre ele pode ver mais na documentação [aqui](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).

> **1 -** Se você já tem o valor que quer passar para o back-end, e este valor não está em um input, mas sim, em forma de texto, você pode pegar este valor através do método jQuery **`text()`**, saiba mais [aqui](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text).
>
> **2 -** Aí é só montar o Ajax, enviando o valor através de uma requisição para uma url que receba e trate este valor.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#envio').on('click', function() {
    let pts = $('#cScore').text();
    
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "processa.php",
      data: pts 
    }) 
    .done(function(pts) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        alert( "Pontuação: " + pts );
      },2000); 
    })
    .fail(function() {
      alert("Não foi enviado mas o valor é: " + pts);
    })
  });
  
})
```

```css
#cScore {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #999;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  Valor total da pontuação:
  <div id='cScore'>100</div>
</div>

<button id="envio">Enviar pontuação</button>
```

**`OBS: O meu exemplo vai retornar o FAIL, pelo motivo de que a url não foi encontrada.`**

Comment: Amigo, muito agradecido é exatamente o que eu precisava, fiz algumas simples adaptações para o meu código e já está funcionando. Grande abraço !

Comment: Ótimo cara, sucesso aí!

Comment: Se de alguma forma a resposta lhe ajudou a sanar suas dúvidas, considere aceitá-la como resposta clicando neste ícone ✔.

Answer (score -1):

0

var escore = $("#cScore").val();

aí so enviar esse "escore" para onde quiser

https://jsfiddle.net/lucasguarasp/4schxv9t/

Comment: `val()` é só para elementos de entrada e não para pegar textos. Pode saber mais aqui https://api.jquery.com/val/#val.